# Sybase / hibernate database performance

Tags: hibernate, sybase, jtds

We have a Sybase database we are querying with a very simple query.

```
Select * from ts_logs where time_sheet_id = 1234
```

The table has approximately 1.1 million records and up until 3 days ago it has been a very quick query performing in approximately a half a second.

Our application uses hibernate and the sql output shows that exact same query. As of three days ago we noticed a tremendous performance decrease where the query now takes 9 to 11 seconds to execute.

We tried running the query within the NetBeans database visualizer where we discover the same performance issue. We initially started determining this to be a database performance issue and decided to further diagnose the issue in dbvisualizer, but to our surprise dbvisualizer was executing the same exact query in less than a half a second.

We are using jtds 1.3 in every environment.

Same database in all environments.

Same query in all environments.

What could be causing the performance bottle neck in hibernate / netbeans, but not dbvisualizer? Any thoughts on the next place to look?

```
CREATE TABLE ts_log (id numeric identity(19) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, log_comment varchar(2500), log_entry varchar(2500) NOT NULL, time_sheet_id numeric(19) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Comment: How many rows does the query return? Maybe DbVisualizer doesn't display all of them and NetBeans does. Or DbVisualizer does not display all the content. Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question. Do you use **identical** parameters for the connection URL in all four environments?

Comment: Updated question with create statement. Default on NetBeans is 1000 rows, total actual rows returned is 2. Identical urls in all environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has likely happened is that query plan has changed, probably due to an increase in the number of rows. You should run UPDATE STATISTICS, and check the query plan. If the search argument is not sufficiently selective to retrieve the desired rows, you should rethink the table/query design.

Comment: We ran update statistics last night and found that it fixed our issue. What we ended up finding was on some machines dbvisualizer would query the table using the table indexes, but on other machines where dbvisualizer was being used it would not use the table indexes despite same driver. I was going to post a question asking what would cause the indexes to not always be used? This appeared to be very consistent behavior among the different machines. Do you happen to have any thoughts on this? It's been running for almost 3 years and all of a sudden became a problem.

Comment: When the data contents change, or tables get fragmented, it is always possible that query plans flip at some point. Therefore, running UPDATE STATISTICS (if possible, UPDATE INDEX STATISTICS) regularly, is part of the normal database maintenance.